# Database and DataTable DateTime format confusion

Tags: wpf, datetime

I want to store a `DateTime.Now` from my WPF C# application to a `DateTime` column in **SQL CE** Database.

I am inserting `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")` then I get the following error:

**String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Couldn't store <2011-54-06 18:54:47> in DateTime Column.  Expected type is DateTime.**

How to store `DateTime` in a specific format to **SQL CE**?

**[EDIT]**

Correction made to: `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

However, after I insert and populate the data to a `DataGrid`. It shows **2011-54-06 18:54:47** in stead of **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss** format. I specify the format to be insert to database but it seem SQL CE has its own way of storing. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just change the `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss` in to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. Obviously it will show like that.Because, you are not inserting the Month but a minute. So, the Datetime is not converted from string format due to wrong format.

Comment: @kaylan, yes that was a mistake, which has been corrected and edited to my question. But SQL CE still store the DateTime to another format..

Comment: according to my Knowledge it should show definitely 2011-07-06 18:54:47 for the Format you given in Edited Correction. But if it gives the same, inside the code before inserting or while populating you are doing some mistake in formats of DateTime.